# Materialize and Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material, materialize

i am using materialize css for my site for design purpose and i am using angularjs to provide fair flexibility to my site but some property of materialize(Select,date-picker,radio-button) did not insert while inserting query it takes blank values from ng-model and when i am talking about radio button so it takes 2nd value when i select 1st or reverse.

So it is my straight Question is..

what is the scope of using materialize or material design or angular material with AngularJS because my priority is to use AngularJS with any of above google design.

please responds as soon as possible

Comment: Can you upload a sample of not working code? Without code unable to explain because all are working you mentioned above. There should be a mistake in the code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Angular-materialize](https://github.com/krescruz/angular-materialize). It has angular directives using Materialize features.